# Is a MIDI file defined as a sound file type?

Tags: audio, compression, midi, file-type

I've just finished an assessment on Data Structures where one of the questions given was regarding MIDI files. In the descriptor (a criteria for assessors) it states the following:

"Candidates will need to demonstrate their knowledge... by showing they can describe:

- At least two Standard File types for images, sounds, video or compression."

Does a MIDI file fall under any of these categories? From what I have searched online, it doesn't. So I am somewhat bemused at a question regarding MIDI files being in this assessment.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no. MIDI tells a synthesizer how to make sounds, where what you can make is constrained by the synthesizer. It cannot be used to represent arbitrary sound data. Though it has been used in a way not originally intended to send small sound samples to a synthesizer.

Compressed sound formats are an entirely different thing from MIDI.

(By the way, the quoted question needs some commas to make sense.)

Answer (score 0):

When I send a MIDI file to my synthesizer, I expect it to produce sounds.